# subcategorization of categorized bar charts(amcharts)

Tags: amcharts

I am looking for subcategorization of categorized bar
 charts(amcharts).  So, the requirement is that subcategory should be
 visible on the landing page without hovering or clicking mouse .So the
 color scheme for subcategorized data should be dialect of the parent
 category.

Comment: Could you edit your post to use standard text formatting?

Comment: Can you be more precise as to what you're looking for? Perhaps a screenshot? Are there any examples from the [AmCharts website](http://www.amcharts.com/demos) that gets you close to what you're looking for?